# select query with multiple conditions on same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

i am having 2 master tables with id

```
ingredients master
------
id int
name varchar(50)

product master
-----
id int
pname varchar(50)

product ingredients
----
inId int (fk - ingredients master)
prId int (fk - product master)
```

now scenario is that a product is having below data

> ingredients master
>   ----- (id , name) {[1 , floor], [2 , salt], [3 , sugar], [4 , oil], [5 , pepper]}
>
> product master
>    ----- (id , pname) {[1 , chapati], [2 , pizza bun], [3 , chappati type 2], [4 , pizza bun type 2]}
>
> product ingredients
>    ----- (inId , prId) {[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2], [4, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3], [1, 4], [2, 4], [3, 4], [4, 4]}

now i want to fire a select query where i could get chapati type 2 as an alternative to chapati or pizza bun type 2 as an alternative to pizza bun

i have tried google and much but cannot come up with a feasible solution.

i just want that which is the exact alternate item of the given item. like chapati and chapati type 2 are completely identical in matter of ingredients. and pizza bun and pizza bun type 2 are completely identical but when i am trying queries it gives all items. as there are some items like floor are common in all.

Comment: You haven't explained your logic at all.  What kind of query are you running?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: i have tried many queries but all returns wired results so i thought better ask experts over here

Comment: Tell at least what is expected output. What records you would like to select? I think `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` might be handy in your situation.

Comment: one recent query i tried was : select distinct prid from product ingredients where inId in (select inId from product ingredients where prId = 1) but that doesnt gives any desired answer

Comment: expected answer is like : if i pass product id of chapati i.e. 1 then i would either get 1,3 or only 3 according to current scenario. or if i pass product id of chapati type 2 i.e. 3 then i should only get product ids of 1,3 or only 1. as these both are having exact identical ingredients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When 2 products have same ingredients, it is considered as alternative products. Each product has multiple ingredients - multiple rows. It is difficult compare values crossing rows. If each product has only 1 ingredient - combine multiple rows to 1 value, it is a lot easier to identify what products have same ingredients.

```
CREATE TABLE #IngredientsMaster
(IngredientId INT
,IngredientName VARCHAR(50)
);
CREATE TABLE #ProductMaster
(ProductId INT
, ProductName VARCHAR(50)
);
CREATE TABLE #ProductIngredients
(IngredientId INT 
,ProductId INT
);
INSERT #IngredientsMaster
VALUES(1 , 'floor'), (2 , 'salt'), (3 , 'sugar'), (4 , 'oil'), (5 , 'pepper');

INSERT #ProductMaster
VALUES(1 , 'chapati'), (2 , 'pizza bun'), (3 , 'chappati type 2'), (4 , 'pizza bun type 2');

INSERT #ProductIngredients  
VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 4)

;WITH cte AS (SELECT pg.ProductId, Productname
                , STUFF((SELECT '-' + cast(t.IngredientId AS VARCHAR(3)) 
                FROM #ProductIngredients t
                WHERE t.productId = pg.productId
                ORDER BY t.ingredientId
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '') AS Ingredients
FROM #ProductIngredients pg
INNER JOIN #IngredientsMaster i
ON i.IngredientId = pg.IngredientId
INNER JOIN #ProductMaster p
ON p.ProductId = pg.ProductId
GROUP BY pg.ProductId, Productname
)
SELECT *
FROM cte cte
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cte t WHERE t.Ingredients = cte.Ingredients AND t.ProductId = 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort wendy.
While thinking much hard i also come up with a solution too... adding another colum with varchar data type to product master and while insert sort and then insert all  values in that column comma seperated or dash seperated and also in transaction table too... that could be easy...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can use this query to obtain the ingredients for chapati and pizza bun type 2 (in common):

```
select ingredients.id
from ingredients master join product master join product ingredients (complete it)
where product.name in ('chapati', 'pizza bun type 2')
group by ingredients.id
having count(*)>1
```

and then you can find product with similar ingredients

```
select product.name
from ingredients master join product master join product ingredients (complete it)
where ingredients.id in (first query)
```

Comment: dear niknik, thanks for the effort you made. i just want that which is the alternate item of the given item. like chapati and chapati type 2 are completely identical in matter of ingredients. and pizza bun and pizza bun type 2 are completely identical but when i am trying queries it gives all items. as there are some items like floor are common in all. expected results is not achiving.